# Unpacking error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterable-unpacking

I'm making a script and i need to do this:

```
for ip, location, zone, dns in data:
```

But i get this error:

```
ValueError: need more than 3 values to unpack
```

The `data` is built it this way:

```
def loadfile():
    nativeFile = open("Zonechilds.csv","r")
    newLine=" "
    data=[]
    while newLine!="":
        newLine=nativeFile.readline()
        if len(newLine)>0:
            if newLine[len(newLine)-1]=="\n":
                newLine=newLine[0:len(newLine)-1]
        data.append(tuple(newLine.split(";")))
    ultimo = data.pop()
    return data
```

A little sample of the csv file:

`200.35.126.30;dnscan01.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs;View_Blackberry;DNSCAN01
0.0.0.0;lac.rac.prueba;View_Blackberry;DNSCAN01
200.35.126.29;dnscan02.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs;View_Blackberry;DNSCAN01
127.0.0.1;localhost.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs;View_Blackberry;DNSCAN01`

When i do:

```
for i in data:  
    print len(i)
```

I get only 4, i can assume that any position of my list data is a 4 member list.

I don't understand why it told me it needed more than 3 members, when i'm giving 4 to it.

What's happening with this code?

Comment: Without showing us how you build `data` we cannot give you any solution.

Comment: Now add some of the data (or sample data) from the csv file.

Comment: In your for loop for in data: print out a value only when the length is != 4. I suspect you have one bad entry, and it is getting lost in the data. Pun intended.

Comment: Can you provide us with a sample of the file? Also, try to print `data`, probably you'll see that there's some 3-element tuple inside.
(By the way, if you're italian I think you'd better subscribe to [this](http://www.python-it.org/smfforum) forum[I guess this by your "ultimo" variable])

Comment: Are you sure you "get only 4"? Try changing `print len(i)` to `if len(i) != 4: print i`, for instance.

Comment: This line i'll make it for test. But i supress it for the code and still get the error.

Comment: Please follow @jorgeca's suggestion.  One of your lines has only three terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside: this the wrong way to read csv data in Python -- use the `csv` module instead.  Your entire code becomes something like:

```
import csv

with open("zonechilds.csv", "rb") as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp, delimiter=";")
    data = [tuple(line) for line in reader]
```

which produces

```
>>> for ip, location, zone, dns in data:
...     print ip, location, zone, dns
... 
200.35.126.30 dnscan01.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs View_Blackberry DNSCAN01
0.0.0.0 lac.rac.prueba View_Blackberry DNSCAN01
200.35.126.29 dnscan02.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs View_Blackberry DNSCAN01 
127.0.0.1 localhost.mnc0004.mcc02de.gprs View_Blackberry DNSCAN01
```

Comment: More comments to the OP code: `newLine[len(newLine)-1]` is written in a more concise way as `newLine[-1]` in Python, and `newLine[0:len(newLine)-1]` is `newLine[:-1]`.

Comment: Just to emphasize for the OP, `open` with `"rb"` is exactly correct for using `csv.reader`, since the reader can control the line ending type expected.

Answer (score 4):

If all the members of data are 4-member tuples or 4-member lists, and you're not modifying any of the later lists in data during your for loop, then I'm pretty sure that there's no possible way you could get this exception when unpacking an element from data.

The two most likely explanations I can see:

1) You're mistaken about where the exception is being raised. It's happening somewhere WITHIN your for loop, rather than when assigning ip, location, zone, and dns. Check your stack trace and make sure the line number really matches the top of the for loop.

2) There is a sneaky 3-member tuple or list somewhere within data. Are you really, really sure that this isn't the case? Does all([len(i) == 4 for i in data]) come out True?

Answer (score 0):

Your file is probably not well formatted as you think. There must be some 3-element tuple inside.

You can check the contents printing out the whole `data` or each element while you iterate over it, for example:

```
for elem in data:
    print(elem)
    ip, location, zone, dns = elem
    #do stuff
```

This allows you to see what's causing the error.

By the way, your code could be written much better, for example:

```
def loadfile():
    native_file = open("Zonechilds.csv","r")
    data = [line.strip('\n').split(';') for line in native_file]
    ultimo = data.pop()
    native_file.close()
    return data
```

(I actually write this answer much more because of this last suggestion of code-style than for the rest of the issue which I think is just easily verifiable wrong assumption)